# Is there a less verbose way to get a DatePickerDialog's value?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, datepickerdialog, timepickerdialog

I'm currently trying to implement `DatePickerDialog` and `TimePickerDialog`, and found out that it's quite verbose to get their values. Like you have to preemptively declare a couple of variables that have to be set on `onDateSet` and `onTimeSet`. I thought that it would be nice if I could create a easily reusable function that would return what values a picker dialog's have. But I can't figure out what needs to be done. I tested using coroutine related stuff like creating a suspend functions for the picker dialog's that looks like this:

```
suspend fun showDatePickerDlg(yr: Int, mth: Int, day: Int): LocalDateTime{
    val res = suspendCoroutine<LocalDateTime> { cont ->
        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(requireActivity(),
            { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->//onDateSet

                cont.resume(LocalDateTime.of(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, 0, 0))
            }, yr, mth, day
        )

        requireActivity().runOnUiThread{
            datePickerDialog.show()
        }
    }

    return res
}
```

This code is inside a fragment btw.

And gets launched like:

```
GlobalScope.async {
    val schedDate = getDatePickerDlg(year, month, day)
    val schedTime = getTimePickerDlg(hour, minute)

    Log.i("TAG", "date: $schedDate")
    Log.i("TAG", "time: $schedTime")
}
```

I might be doing something wrong because the dialogs aren't showing even with `runOnUiThread`, which I think was necessary because anything inside a suspend are technically not on the main/ui thread.

But my main question is still is what the title says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [recommended way to do it in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/pickers) is much more verbose than what you seemed to be doing before creating your suspend function! This is because they recommend that you host your Dialog inside a DialogFragment (so it will be preserved under configuration changes or when the app is suspended and comes back).

If you don't mind the dialog disappearing when the screen rotates, you can skip that, but you are still left with having to use the listener.

I'm not exactly sure what you are describing when you say you have to pre-emptively declare variables. You still have to use the variable inside the listener, because the code outside the listener is called first. So really, your flow should look like this:

```
DatePickerDialog(requireActivity(), { _, pickedYear, pickedMonth, pickedDay ->
    val schedDate = LocalDateTime.of(pickedYear, pickedMonth + 1, pickedDay)

    TimePickerDialog(requireActivity(), { _, pickedHour, pickedMinute ->
        val schedTime = LocalTime.of(pickedHour, pickedMinute)

        // Use schedDate and schedTime in here....
        // ...
        // ...

    }, initialHour, initialMinute, false).show()

}, initialYear, initialMonth, initialDay).show()
```

So yes, this nested callback looks horrible, and could be improved with suspend functions. But remember, this is not compatible with DialogFragments.

---

Here are some problems with your coroutine solution:

- DatePickerDialog's listener returns a 0-based month, but LocalDateTime uses a 1-based month, so you need to add 1 to the month.
- You used `suspendCoroutine` instead of `suspendCancellableCoroutine`, so if your coroutine is cancelled, the stuff inside the lambda is leaked.
- Your suspend function doesn't handle the case where the user dismisses the dialog without choosing a date. If this happens, your coroutine will be stuck in a suspended state forever.
- You create the dialog on whatever background thread the coroutine might be using. I don't think this is supported. You need to be on the main thread to create and show the dialog.
- You launched your coroutine with `GlobalScope` instead of `lifecycleScope`, so your coroutines leaks the Activity and the Fragment.
- You used `async` instead of `launch` even though your coroutine isn't intended to return anything.

Here is how I would define the suspend function to handle cancellation and be called on the proper thread. I would also make it a Context extension function so you can reuse it in any activity or fragment.

```
suspend fun Context.getDateFromUser(initialDate: LocalDate = LocalDate.now()): LocalDate? = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
        val onCancel = DialogInterface.OnCancelListener {
            cont.resume(null)
        }
        val onSet = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, month, day ->
            cont.resume(LocalDate.of(year, month + 1, day))
        }
        val dialog = DatePickerDialog(this@getDateFromUser, onSet, initialDate.year, initialDate.month -1, initialDate.dayOfMonth).apply {
            onCancelListener = onCancel
            show()
        }
        cont.invokeOnCancellation { dialog.cancel() } 
    }
}
```

In a fragment you might use it like this:

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    val schedDate = requireActivity().getDateFromUser() ?: someDefaultLocalDate
    val schedTime = requireActivity().getTimeFromUser() ?: someDefaultLocalTime

    // Use schedDate and schedTime in here....
    // ...
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not really that used to coroutines yet, it's quite complex to be fair, so that's one of the reason I made this question. So I think I'd be using your suggestions.